# Call IBAction method from code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a button findTarget_Btn on which I want to call a method moreDetails. 
In viewDidLoad, I am writing

```
[findTarget_Btn addTarget:self action:@selector(moreDetails) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But for some reason moreDetails is not getting called when I click the button? Am I doing something wrong?

Also is it fine if I call 2 methods on the button; 1 via IB and other via code similar to above ?

Comment: please add NSLog(@"Button: %@", findTarget_Btn); in front of this line. I have the feeling that your button is nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check how your `moreDetails` is defined. Most likely, it takes `id sender` parameter: in this case you should use `@selector(moreDetails:)` (colon signature reflects presence of parameter in)

Regarding your second question: yes, you can definitely call other actions from your code. `IBAction` is just a synonym for `void`, it's no different from any other method.

**edit**
I might have misunderstood your second question. If you want to assign one action in IB and another one in the code, that might not work. But you can always create a dedicated handler and call two methods sequentially from it.

```
- (IBAction) findTargetClick:(id) sender {
  [self handler1:sender];
  [self moreDetails:sender];
}
```

Comment: It's probably worth checking that findTarget_Btn does actually point to something too; just to rule out a misclick in Interface Builder.

Comment: if a wrong method signature would be the issue he would get an unrecognized selector exception.

Comment: There is no parameter. Here is how I have it
-(IBAction) moreDetails{...}

Comment: @hmthur I would try going with 1 handler, then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you've assigned something to `findTarget_Btn`?  If you forgot to initialise it or if you are using a nib and forgot to hook it up as an outlet, then it will be nil, so any messages you send to it will be ignored.

Comment: it is not nil..checked IB connection also